How does one know if God is meaningful?
Many people ascribe god to be a meaningful entity even if the “evidence” for this may be that us merely talking about god already implies that it has meaning.
But both theists and atheists alike don’t understand how god operates. Without this how or a clear understanding of what god even is, how can one figure out whether it is a meaningful (in the sense of every attribute of Him having meaning) proposition in the first place?
Just to take a specific example, to many theists, God exists outside of time. But given that we have no experience of anything existing “outside of time”, how do we know that this very concept is meaningful, much less coherent, in the first place?
——
“What are the definitions of god?” is very obviously different than “is god meaningful?” so this is not a duplicate as one of the commenters below suggests.

I recommend to ask this question in a religious or theological blog. - Concerning the point of your question I share your concern.

I’m voting to close this question because it is better asked at https://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Thank you for sharing my concern but how is whether or not God is a meaningful proposition not part of philosophy if theism is part of philosophy?

Questions about the meaning of certain religious or theological concepts are better first addressed to the followers of the religion. Not until one knows what the faithful mean with their words and how they argue, can one assess these concepts from a philosophical point of view. – In  my view it would be OK, when you first present some authentic religious/theological answers and then ask for a philosophical reply to these answers.

@JoWehler I literally linked an article that is from an encyclopedia of philosophy that deals with conceptual issues of god. Articles such these and these do so as well. Are you saying these are not part of philosophy? It is true that certain religious people may have more knowledge about these concepts but conceptual foundations of god and whether or not god is meaningful is part of philosophy

Of course one can debate with religious scholars about these concepts. Stanford Online encyclopedia is a good source. The discussion keeps going and going since millenia. IMO is has more weight to hear first the original tone of the believers. They use the god-concept to express their existential experience.

I think your links are not really getting at the issue -- Richard Swinburne is a good person to read on meaningfulness of religious language : https://archive.org/details/coherenceoftheis0000swin as well this https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/religious-language/

And this link: https://iep.utm.edu/rel-lang/

@MauroALLEGRANZA fair, although semantics aside, I feel as if the roots of the question were obvious. Nevertheless, edited.

This question is similar to: What are the main definitions of god in philosophy?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. I think this question could also be closed as belonging to Christianity, but there are valid questions about gods in philosophy. Luckily we have enough of those already to close as duplicate anyway.

@tkruse “What are the definitions of god?” is very obviously different than “is god meaningful?” If your point is that there are some similarities between questions, then that is subjective and you can argue that for almost any pair of questions. In either case, it doesn’t make it a duplicate.

There are many ways to phrase an inquiry into the same issue.

@tkruse into what you perceive as the same issue*

We can talk meaningfully about unicorns, even though we know that they're physically impossible in the real world.

"Mu." Now you have the zen exercise of trying to figure out why that is the answer.

From a strict logical positivist POV, God is unverifiable, hence meaningless.
From a classical logic POV, God is self-contradictory (Stone paradox, omniscience-free will paradox, Epicurean trilemma, etc.), hence incoherent.

For a more balanced account see here. Courtesy, Rushi

@MauroALLEGRANZA The idea of separate, non-overlapping magisteria is a relatively new concept. A lot of ancient theology involves classical logic.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I thought if we are to philosophize about G then we must so logically.

While I agree with this answer (and approve the accept FWIW) you could add the povs of (1) Phenomenology (2) Existentialism (Kierkegaard) (3) mysticism (4) pantheism

See

@Rushi, I made the necessary edit to my post.

Meaning comes from shared use. There is no need to "know" if "God" (which isn't a proposition) or a proposition about any God is meaningful. If one can communicate effectively with others, then one's propositions have meaning. If a proposition such as "God exists outside of time" does not convey anything to the recipient, they'll ask for clarification.

But if the proponent cannot also outline what “exists outside of time” means or how it operates, how do we know whether such a thing is meaningful, much less possible? It is true that the individual words of that phrase objectively have meaning, but how do we know if the combination does?


… to many theists, God exists outside of time.  But given that we have
no experience of anything existing “outside of time”. How do we know
that this very concept is meaningful, much less coherent, in the first
place?

For every other knowledge needs time.  If something before experiencing, while experiencing and after experiencing (more precisely...always) is the same and which is formless it cannot be taken as a mere concept.  I don’t know if all religions agree with this idea.  Since it is incomparable, the only solution is to experience it.  IMHO, I think the main flaw is that even though it is behind/behind concept, we have limited it under the definition of the concept.
